# How to patch bash sourcefiles in a script

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I'm trying to write a script, which is downloading Bash and the latest security Patches:

```
cd ~/sources

mkdir bash && cd $_
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4.tar.gz

wget -r -np -nd --reject="index.html*,.sig" https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/
nfiles=$(ls | wc -l)
tar zxf bash-4.4.tar.gz && cd bash-4.4

echo "Patching sourcefiles..."
for i in ../bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]; do patch -p0 -s < $nfiles; done

echo "Compiling GNU bash..."
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
cp -f /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

I'm using wget to get all the patch files (12 of them) and im saving it with `nfiles=$(ls | wc -l)` into that variable.
Theres the first problem... the content of nfiles is 13 because the bash-4.4.tar.gz is counting too, but I only have 12 patch files.

Now im trying to patch it right here:

`for i in ../bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]; do patch -p0 -s < $nfiles; done`

But this doesnt work, he isnt patching from bash44-001 to bash44-012...
The nfiles variable contains 12(13) as number, but I need another format to make it work like 012.

I hope you guys can understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your problem perfectly but I will try to help anyway.

**Problem 1:** `$(ls | wc -l)` returns more rows than required.

If I want to be sure that only the correct files are counted, I always use `find` -- something like this might work for you:

```
$(find . -name "bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]" | wc -l)
```

**Problem 2:** Wildcard `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` does not keep numeric order.

I find strange that variable `i` is used nowhere inside the `for` loop.

Try something like:

```
for i in `eval echo "{000..0$nfiles}"`; do echo "bash44-$i"; done
```

**General problem:**

If you are trying to do something with a list of directories of format "`bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]`" and you want to do it in a ascending order, I would simply do:

```
for dir in `find . -type d -name "bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]" | sort`; do
  something_with "$dir"
done
```

Comment: I'm trying to explain my problem a bit better:
I'm downloading the bash-4.4.tar.gz and the patches they are named like (bash44-001, bash44-002  [....]  bash44-012)

Than I'm trying to patch the sourcfiles with the downloaded security patches (bash44-001 [...] etc).

For that loop I was trying to use that nfiles=$(ls | wc -l) line.
-> Run the patching loop until you reached the amount of files in the folder (the last bash44-0xx patch file)

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
nfiles=$(ls | wc -l)
```

to

```
nfiles=$(wc -l < <(printf '%s\n' bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]))
```

That would exclude `bash-4.4.tar.gz` from being counted.

Even better, you could store the regex in a variable and use it in both places:

```
file_regex='bash44-[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
nfiles=$(wc -l < <(printf '%s\n' $file_regex))
```

and later

```
for i in $file_regex; do patch ...
```

I am not sure about `< $nfiles` - that would treat the content of `nfiles` variable as a file, which isn't the case here.  Did you mean to say `patch -p0 -s $nfiles`?  If you really want `patch` command to read the number from stdin, then you need this:

```
patch -p0 -s <(echo $nfiles)
```

---

See also:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I'm trying to explain my problem a bit better:
I'm downloading the bash-4.4.tar.gz and the patches they are named like (bash44-001, bash44-002  [....]  bash44-012)

Than I'm trying to patch the sourcfiles with the downloaded security patches (bash44-001 [...] etc).

For that loop I was trying to use that nfiles=$(ls | wc -l) line.
-> Run the patching loop until you reached the amount of files in the folder (the last bash44-0xx patch file)

Comment: You are already looping once per each qualifying `bash44-???` file.  Not sure why you need `nfiles` at all.